# Xpath wildcards

Tags: xpath, firebug, scrapy

I am using scrapy to scrape some content but I am having trouble with xpaths, specifically, I am trying to get to the portion:

**div class = "app_content_section shorten-enable"**
(the second last line in the image)

I find that sometimes scrapy does not like the xpath given by firebug. Therefore,in my python script I do the following:

**sel.xpath('//*[contains(@class, "app_content_section shorten-enable")]')**

but nothing gets returned and I am not sure why this is the case. Any pointers would be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: The XPath itself seems to be fine. You can try it out directly within Firebug using the [$x() command](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/$x). It will return the element(s) containing the class.

Comment: What happens if you try a slight variant? `sel.xpath('//*[@class="app_content_section shorten-enable"]')

Comment: thanks, I think I have narrowed down the problem. You are correct in that there is nothing wrong with the Xpath itself. However, I was scraping some data in an authenticated session in scrapy. I inspected the response I obtain, and it is not the same as what I see in the browser. I am not sure why that is happening, especially because I don't see any javascript/AJAX that would explain this

Comment: Perhaps try explicitly setting the `USER-AGENT` setting to a browser and see if that gives you a different response?